# Optimization Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my zeal to improve as developer, I want to know my code it is possible to improve, I am new in this and have very small logical

this is my code:

```
private int Period(DateTime date)
{
    int period = 0;

    if(date!= null)
    {
        int numeroMes = int.Parse(date.Month.ToString());
        if(numeroMes <= 2)
        {
            period = 1;
        }
        else if (numeroMes <= 4 && numeroMes > 2)
        {
            periodo = 2;
        }
        else if (numeroMes <= 6 && numeroMes > 4)
        {
            period = 3;
        }
        else if (numeroMes <= 8 && numeroMes > 6)
        {
            period  = 4;
        }
        else if (numeroMes <= 10 && numeroMes > 8)
        {
            period = 5;
        }
        else if (numeroMes <= 12 && numeroMes > 8)
        {
            period = 6;
        }
    }

    return period ;
}
```

tkns for help me.

Comment: This question is a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: switch statement i would look into

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "improve". Make it more readable? Move this to Code Review as was mentioned. Make it more performant? Learn to use a profiler.

Comment: Thank you, it will eliminate the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the period since every period is just two months.

As DaveShaw pointed out, there is no need to check for the date being null because DateTime is a value type and thus cannot be null.

```
private int Period(DateTime date)
{
    // already an int, no need to convert
    var month = date.Month;
    if (month % 2 == 0)
        return month / 2;
    else
        return (month + 1) / 2
}
```

Here's another even shorter option that A.S. suggested.

```
private int Period(DateTime date)
{
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(date.Month / 2.0);
    // or...
    // return (date.Month + 1) / 2;
    // but I prefer the Ceiling option since it is more obvious what is happening
}
```

Alternatively, you could also reduce your code in this way...

```
private int Period(DateTime date)
{
    int month = date.Month;
    if (month <= 2)
        return 1;
    else if (month <= 4)
        return 2;
    else if (month <= 6)
        return 3;
    else if (month <= 8)
        return 4;
    else if (month <= 10)
        return 5;
    else
        return 6;
}
```

Since I used return statements, there is no need for the second bool in each if statement.

Comment: Date can't be null, it's a value type

Comment: would it not be quicker to use division by 2 with Math.ceil()? It seems there are quite a few repeated if-statements that could be shortened.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the flooring of integer division to your favour which should be faster.

```
private int Period(DateTime date)
{
    return (date.Month + 1) / 2;
}
```

However rounding might be easier to understand.

```
private int Period(DateTime date)
{
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(date.Month / 2.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said, this would better fit in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since it's not a question to a problem.

Now for some improvements to your code.

```
if(date!= null)
```

This will always be true, since DateTime is a value type (struct), which can't be null. Only Nullable<DateTime>/DateTime? can be null. So you can simply remove that.

```
int numeroMes = int.Parse(date.Month.ToString());
```

Here you are converting date.Month (which is an int) to a string and then parse it back to an int. Don't do that, date.Month is an int already:

```
int numeroMes = date.Month;
```

The rest is ok so far, but i guess in this line:

```
else if (numeroMes <= 12 && numeroMes > 8)
```

you really meant numeroMes > 10. Doesn't make a difference though as values 9 and 10 are matched before that.

Finally, you could shorten all those ifs to a simple formula:

```
return (int)Math.Ceiling(date.Month / 2.0);
```

Math.Ceiling rounds up the passed decimal number to the next integral number. So 1.5 would become 2 for example.